# how to support supporting older android versions in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-3.0-honeycomb, backwards-compatibility, android-2.2-froyo

My app need to target API level 7 and above, however I'd like to selectively use functionality from newer releases when it becomes available.  For instance, I might have code like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
    base64String = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
} else {
    base64String = MyCustomBase64.encodeBytes(bytes);
}
```

However, when I configure the project in eclipse to target "Android 2.1" (API 7) the class android.util.Base64 isn't found since it only exists for API 8 and above.  Eclipse then designates that line as a compile error (red "x") since the class isn't on the build path.

My question: what is the "proper" way to handle this sort of development (supporting features that don't actually exist in one's target environment) when doing Android development using Eclipse?

I can always change the target in Eclipse to 2.2 (API 8), but that's not ideal either.  It creates the situation where I might unknowingly use a feature that only exists in 8+ and not be notified of that fact by Eclipse.

Comment: what is your MyCustomBase64? I have same problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered your own question.

> I can always change the target in Eclipse to 2.2 (API 8)

That is how it is done. You can still set the minSDK/targetSDK in your manifest to 7. AFAIK you'll just have to use the if statements like you've shown around any code that is from a higher API level.

Comment: Surrounding code from future API levels with if statements doesn't prevent them from showing up as compile errors when the project target is set to 2.1.

This document seems to describe the preferred method:

http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck

Comment: It seems there may be a bug, however.  I used String.isEmpty() in my code, while using a target API of 9 and a min level of 7 (in manifest) and it wasn't flagged as an error by the Lint checker.  It should have been.

Comment: hmm Haven't played around with the lint tool before it seems nifty. I think there is no way for you to avoid compile errors if you are going to keep it built with API 7 but want to use features from API 8. I believe that your only option is to build the project with the higher level API

Comment: The build process (which I inherited, and is "black magic" to some degree) uses gradle, and the product is an APK that installs and runs on API level 8 devices properly.  I'm assuming it reads the minSdkVersion setting from the manifest and builds according to that.